# Saving persistent World Anchors on HoloLens2 locally

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I am currently working on a Room-Scale Unity-Project where I need to use persistent World Anchors to save `GameObject`s' positions locally on my device without any Internet Access or Wifi in use.

I am using `Unity 2019.4.7` and a `HoloLens2` device.

I came across some implementations from earlier `HoloLens1` Projects as well as the `WorldAnchorManager`-Class of `MRTK 2.4` which seems pretty similar to the old `WorldAnchorManager` of `HoloToolkit`. (For Example: https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/2667/how-to-use-unity-world-anchors, or https://codeholo.com/2019/02/01/anchoring-your-gameobjects-in-hololens-apps)

Unfortunately no Solution worked for me.

It seems like `WorldAnchors` aren't even being saved in the `WorldAnchorStore`. I also tried to use the official Unity `WorldAnchorStore` without the `WorldAnchorManager`-Class even if it's going to be deprecated in `Unity 2020`.

Can somebody please provide me an example that should work in my setup?

I would also be glad about every single hint to make the anchors work.

My current Code with `WorldAnchorManager` looks like the following. Persistent anchors in the `WorldAnchorManager`-Instance is enabled.

```
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Experimental.Utilities;
using UnityEngine;

public class SetWorldAnkeredObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject anchoredObject;
    public WorldAnchorManager store;
    private string anchorId = "AnchoredCube";
    private bool savedRoot;

    void Start()
    {
        store.AttachAnchor(anchoredObject, anchorId);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
        {
            store.AttachAnchor(anchoredObject, anchorId);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            if (anchoredObject != null)
                store.RemoveAnchor(anchorId);
            anchoredObject.transform.position = this.transform.position;
            store.AttachAnchor(anchoredObject, anchorId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some lines of codes taken from a project of mine that may help you.

IMPORT

```
    private byte[] _importedData;
    private int _retryCount = 3;

    internal bool ImportAnchors()
    {
        _retryCount = 3;
        string path = GetWorldAnchorsDataPath(); // your path
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            Debug.Log("Fail ImportWorldAnchors ImportAnchors File does not exist");
            return false;
        }

        _importedData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        Debug.Log("_importedData count " + _importedData.Length);
        WorldAnchorTransferBatch.ImportAsync(_importedData, OnImportComplete);
    }

    private void OnImportComplete(SerializationCompletionReason completionReason, WorldAnchorTransferBatch deserializedTransferBatch)
    {
        if (completionReason != SerializationCompletionReason.Succeeded)
        {
            Debug.Log("(" + _retryCount + ") Failed to import: " + completionReason.ToString());
            if (_retryCount > 0)
            {
                _retryCount--;
                WorldAnchorTransferBatch.ImportAsync(_importedData, OnImportComplete);
            }
            return;
        }
        Debug.Log("Success ImportWorldAnchors OnImportComplete, anchors count : " + deserializedTransferBatch.anchorCount);
        AnchorsManager.GetAndUpdateAnchorsFromBatch(deserializedTransferBatch);

        deserializedTransferBatch.Dispose();
    }    

  internal static string GetWorldAnchorsDataPath()
    {
        return Application.persistentDataPath + "/worldAnchors.dat";
    }
```

EXPORT

```
 internal void ExportAnchors()
    {            
        string path = GetWorldAnchorsDataPath();
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            FileStream fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);

            /* 
             * Set the length of filestream to 0 and flush it to the physical file.
             *
             * Flushing the stream is important because this ensures that
             * the changes to the stream trickle down to the physical file.
             * 
             */
            fileStream.SetLength(0);
            fileStream.Close(); // This flushes the content, too.
        }

        WorldAnchorTransferBatch transferBatch = new WorldAnchorTransferBatch();

        AddAnchorsToBatch(transferBatch); // your own function to use your batch
        Debug.Log("Nb anchors in batch : " + transferBatch.anchorCount);
        WorldAnchorTransferBatch.ExportAsync(transferBatch, OnExportDataAvailable, OnExportComplete);
    }

    private void OnExportDataAvailable(byte[] data)
    {
        AppendAllBytes(GetWorldAnchorsDataPath(), data);    
    }

    private void OnExportComplete(SerializationCompletionReason completionReason)
    {
        if (completionReason != SerializationCompletionReason.Succeeded)
        {
            SendExportFailedToClient();
        }
        else
        {
            SendExportSucceededToClient();
        }
    }

    private void SendExportFailedToClient()
    {
        Debug.Log("Export fail");
        string path = GetWorldAnchorsDataPath();
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }
        SuccessToExportWorldAnchors(false);
    }

    private void SendExportSucceededToClient()
    {
        Debug.Log("Export succeed");
        SuccessToExportWorldAnchors(true);
    }


    private static void AppendAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
    {
        //argument-checking here.

        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Luckypon, I will check this out today and give feedback whether this works for me or not!

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the path of holens2?

I looked it up and found that you used "KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary." Can I get a path with Unity's "Application.persistentDataPath"?